# jenkins chinese input arguments

Tags: jenkins

I have one jenkins build project which has one string argument on Linux, but it cannot receive Chinese string argument correctly. e.g. I try to print it using echo ${sql}, sql is my argument variable, I inut "北京", but jenkins shows in console output is below:

```
echo '??'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How up to date is your version of Jenkins?

There was a [patch back in May 2013](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/775).

Also, unicode for the **console** was [more recently resolved](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13838) on Sept 27.

If your Jenkins runs on Ubuntu, note that it uses the [system locale at JVM startup time](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/51DgNdYuruc).

Hope that helps.